# How can i merge multiple 2d array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Merge this array in javascript

```
const arr = [
    [ 1, '2', '6', 854301 ],
    [ 1, '2', '6', 854302 ],
    [ 1, '2', '6', 854303 ]
],
[
    [ 1, '3', '7', 854304 ],
    [ 1, '3', '7', 854305 ],
    [ 1, '3', '7', 854306 ]
]
```

I want this array output response as like below :

```
[
    [ 1, '2', '6', 854301 ],
    [ 1, '2', '6', 854302 ],
    [ 1, '2', '6', 854303 ],
    [ 1, '3', '7', 854304 ],
    [ 1, '3', '7', 854305 ],
    [ 1, '3', '7', 854306 ]
]
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read our [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to get a better understanding about how to add a [*minimal*, *reproducible* example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Call [`Array.prototype.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) on the nested array.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use [Array.prototype.flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) method.

```js
const arr = [
  [
    [ 1, '2', '6', 854301 ],
    [ 1, '2', '6', 854302 ],
    [ 1, '2', '6', 854303 ]
  ],
  [
    [ 1, '3', '7', 854304 ],
    [ 1, '3', '7', 854305 ],
    [ 1, '3', '7', 854306 ]
  ]
];

const res = arr.flat();

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.reduce`:

```js
const arr = [
  [
    [ 1, '2', '6', 854301 ],
    [ 1, '2', '6', 854302 ],
    [ 1, '2', '6', 854303 ]
  ],
  [
    [ 1, '3', '7', 854304 ],
    [ 1, '3', '7', 854305 ],
    [ 1, '3', '7', 854306 ]
  ]
];

const res = arr.reduce((acc,list) => acc.concat(list), []);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Why are you putting the arrays into array just to reduce them into another array? `const arr3 = [...arr1, ...arr2];` or `const arr3 = arr1.concat(arr2)` would suffice.

Comment: @RichardDunn it's an array of matrices, so you need to iterate and accumulate the concatenation at every iteration

Comment: Ah, my mistake, I thought the author was trying to merge two separate arrays. I need to read more carefully...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `concat()` function

a and b are you two arrays.

```
var c = a.concat(b);

console.log(c);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use ES6 array spread operator

const array3 = [...array1, ...array2]

then just log it